# Is there a cli command to dump the ACL associated to a file (in a MacOS context)?

Tags: macos, command-line, acl

I would like to know if it is possible, and if it is, how can be seen the ACL (Access Control List) associated to a file in a MacOS context, using command line (not using the GUI "File Information" tab, I mean).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `man ls`:

```
-e      Print the Access Control List (ACL) associated with the file, if
        present, in long (-l) output.
```